# Test whether the middle point within a sliding interval is its maximum

Tags: matlab, performance, max, vectorization, windowing

```
lengthData = 1500;
data = rand(lengthData,1);
result = zeros(floor(lengthData/2),lengthData);
for i = 1:floor(lengthData/2)-1
    for j = 1+i:length(data)-i
        if data(j) == max(data(j-i:j+i))
            result(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
```

I have a data points of a specified `lengthData` stored in variable `data`. Now I am trying to find the maximum value in an specified interval, where interval lengths are increasing.

One quick observation is that as the interval size is increased, the number of entries in a particular row in `result` is decreasing. Following is a plot of `sum(result,2)` to verify that code is working as intended.

[image]

However, this code is taking a long time to execute. For larger values of `lengthData` (of about 6000), time taken is almost 22 seconds ( up from 0.4 seconds with `lengthData` of 1500).

Is there an alternate way I can implement my logic or to vectorize it, to somehow speed it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460665/test-whether-the-middle-point-within-a-sliding-interval-is-its-maximum#comment99514674_56460665):

> Maxima is occuring at the middle of window in my implementation of code. May be I was not clear in the problem description. I am looking for various maxima. There is only one global maxima but there are many local maxima. Now there local maximas can only exist when they are greater than numbers in their immediate vicinity. This vicinity I am considering as lenght of moving window. A particular value may be local maxima when sliding window is 5 but it may not be local maxima when sliding window is increased to 10.(...)

I suggest to take a look at [`findpeaks()`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) which does exactly that: finding local maxima. Your "sliding window length" would then be incorporated into the `'MinPeakDistance'` name-value pair, and the minimum height you mention in the question would be given by `'MinPeakHeight'`.

Answer (score 2):

I have run code using the [vectorization solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56461291) and also using `findpeaks()`. This function is giving me the desired result with better time performance, see the following benchmark:

```
tic;
lengthData=6000;
data=rand(lengthData,1);
result=zeros(floor(lengthData/2),lengthData);
for i=1:floor(lengthData/2)-1
    for j=1+i:length(data)-i
        if(data(j)==max(data(j-i:j+i)))
            result(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
toc;

tic;
result1=zeros(floor(lengthData/2),lengthData);
for i=1:floor(lengthData/2)-1
    del = 2*i+1;
    ind_arr = [];
    ind_arr(:,1) = 1:lengthData+1-del;
    ind_arr(:,2:del) = 1;
    ind_arr = cumsum(ind_arr,2);
    data_arr = data(ind_arr);
    [~,max_ind] = max(data_arr,[],2);
    result1(i,1+i:length(data)-i) = max_ind==(i+1);
end
toc;


tic;
result2=zeros(floor(lengthData/2),lengthData);

for i=1:floor(lengthData/2)-1

    [~,locs]=findpeaks(data,'MinPeakDistance',i);
    result2(i,1:length(locs))=locs;
end
toc;
```

Results in:

```
Elapsed time is 23.317170 seconds.   % Original
Elapsed time is 312.340804 seconds.  % Vectorized
Elapsed time is 3.053548 seconds.    % findpeaks()
```

I use MATLAB R2018a, on a Xeon 3.4 processor with 32GB RAM.

Comment: Just as a side-note: timing with `tic/toc` is discouraged for benchmarking, for various reasons; [`timeit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) is recommended instead.  Since this concerns orders of magnitude, however, the conclusion will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to vectorize the inner loop with the following...

```
lengthData=1500;
data=rand(lengthData,1);
result=zeros(floor(lengthData/2),lengthData);

for i=1:floor(lengthData/2)-1

    del = 2*i+1;
    ind_arr = [];
    ind_arr(:,1) = 1:lengthData+1-del;
    ind_arr(:,2:del) = 1;
    ind_arr = cumsum(ind_arr,2);

    data_arr = data(ind_arr);

    [~,max_ind] = max(data_arr,[],2);

    result(i,1+i:length(data)-i) = max_ind==(i+1);

end
```

There's probably a cleaner way to build `ind_arr` but this appears to give matching results to your original code.

Running it through the profiler in R2014b it shows

```
  time   calls  line
             1    1 lengthData=1500; 
             1    2 data=rand(lengthData,1); 
             1    3 result=zeros(floor(lengthData/2),lengthData); 
             1    4 result2 = result; 
                  5 
             1    6 t1ID = tic; 
                  7 
             1    8 for i=1:floor(lengthData/2)-1 
           749    9     for j=1+i:length(data)-i 
  3.66  561750   10         if(data(j)==max(data(j-i:j+i))) 
< 0.01    4276   11             result(i,j)=1; 
          4276   12         end 
  0.70  561750   13     end 
           749   14 end 
                 15 
             1   16 fprintf('Original Time: %g\n',toc(t1ID)); 
                 17 
             1   18 t2ID = tic; 
                 19 
             1   20 for i=1:floor(lengthData/2)-1 
                 21     
           749   22     del = 2*i+1; 
  0.02     749   23     ind_arr = []; 
< 0.01     749   24     ind_arr(:,1) = 1:lengthData+1-del; 
  0.45     749   25     ind_arr(:,2:del) = 1; 
  0.51     749   26     ind_arr = cumsum(ind_arr,2); 
                 27 
  1.42     749   28     data_arr = data(ind_arr); 
                 29 
  0.52     749   30     [~,max_ind] = max(data_arr,[],2); 
                 31 
  0.05     749   32     result2(i,1+i:length(data)-i) = max_ind==(i+1); 
                 33     
           749   34 end 
                 35 
             1   36 fprintf('Single Loop Time: %g\n',toc(t2ID));
```

```
Original Time: 4.53376
Single Loop Time: 2.81267
```

Comment: Did you benchmark this? Is there an improvement in terms of runtime? Which MATLAB version did you test it on?

Comment: This code is way slower than the original. Original one takes 0.4 seconds and this one is taking over 4 seconds. Matlab 2018a

Comment: Testing on R2014b, it looks like on average it's a ~55% runtime improvement. The slowest portion is the creation of `data_arr`.

Comment: @Hal9000. It appears that max function has improved considerably in Matlab 2018a. Line 10 in your profiler code is taking total time of 0.409 seconds in 2018a version whereas it is taking 3.66 in older version

Comment: @lonstud ahhhh.... there's the discrepancy. Disregard my answer then, unless you're desperate enough to run ancient versions.

Comment: I think this happens because of the JIT rework in version R2016a, which increased loop speed quite considerably. In any case, the `findpeaks()` solution is the fastest even before that version. Do keep the answer around, as it is another solution, and might give more insight.